# How do you return a data object from a subactivity in a UML activity diagram?

Tags: uml, flowchart, workflow-activity

I'm trying to create a subactivity that outputs a data object.

Currently, I have a subactivity, **Prepare Pack**, that adds a Joker card to the `Card Pack` data object, removes all twos, threes and fours from `Card Pack` and returns `Card Pack`.

[image]

To model an output I connected the subactivity to `Card Pack` data object with an arrow. Is this a valid way of illustrating that the subactivity returns `Card Pack`?

Comment: Except that the flow for the joker card should be vice versa it looks plausible to me. The boundary notation looks suspicious, though, Will have a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks for the feedback! The boundary notation is what I'm most uncertain about. It's really difficult to find examples of a subactivity that returns something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I would model it. Given you have the sub-activity modeled with containing actions like this

[image]

the card deck is fed in via an object node and leaving via a second one. Another view shows that without the inner structure:

[image]

(Note that the lying 8 is a decoration from Enterprise Architect to show the the element is clickable and contains a diagram showing its inner structure.)

Now this activity can be used as invocation like this:

[image]